# How do I check StyleOption state in Pyside6?

Tags: pyside6, qstyle

So I'm trying to determine what or how can I determine particular state of StyleOption. I used the '==' operator but building a QPushbutton it seems like it returns sometimes True and sometimes False for a particular metric.

**Main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from CustomStyle import MyStyles


# Subclass QMainWindow to customize your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Widgets App")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # button
        mPushBtn = QPushButton('click')
        mPushBtn.setFlat(True)
        layout.addWidget(mPushBtn)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        # Set the central widget of the Window. Widget will expand
        # to take up all the space in the window by default.
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle(MyStyles('QPushButton'))
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

**CustomStyle.py**

```
from typing import Optional, Union

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *

class MyStyles(QCommonStyle):
    def __init__(self, which_widget: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(which_widget)
        self.widget_name = which_widget

        self.setObjectName('fpStyles')

    def pixelMetric(self, m: QStyle.PixelMetric, opt: Optional[QStyleOption], widget: Optional[QWidget]) -> int:
        if widget.__class__.__name__ == self.widget_name:
            print(f'PixelMetric: metric > {m.name.decode()} -- styleOption > {opt.__class__.__name__} -- widget > {widget.__class__.__name__}')
            if opt is not None: print(f'\tsize >>> {opt.rect.getRect()}')
            if opt is not None: print(f'{opt.state == QStyle.State_Enabled}')
        return super().pixelMetric(m, opt, widget)
```

Running the above produces following output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QStyle [`State`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#StateFlag-enum) enum is a *flag*:

> It stores an OR combination of StateFlag values.

This means that you cannot use the equality comparison, because using `==` will return `True` only if the state is **exactly** `State_Enabled`.

The correct operator is `&`, which will mask the bits that are equal to the given value, and that can be converted to a bool to check its truthfulness:

```
print(f'{bool(opt.state & QStyle.State_Enabled)}')
```

To clarify, `State_Enable` corresponds to `1` (both binary and integer, obviously), but if the state also contains another flag such as `State_Raised` (which is `2`, or binary `10`), `state` will be `3`, or binary `11`.

`3 == 1` obviously returns `False`, but `3 & 1` masks the rightmost bit of `3`, resulting in `1`, and `bool(1)` results `True`.

Read more about [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Be aware that QCommonStyle is the basis for a *completely new* style. You should normally use [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproxystyle.html).

<sup>Note: assuming your imports are done consistently, it's usually better to use `isinstance(obj, cls)` instead of comparing the class name.</sup>

Comment: ah.. perfect, i tried that too.. but it was returning me an object, silly me didn't thought of wrapping it around bool() ... duh haha.. Thanks a lot. Also thanx, for the class name comparison tip :)